# Node-RED crashed [error] [function:Status] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, node-red

*[error]* [function:Status] **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.**

My node red project crased because i linked output html-node with input switch-node

[image: click here to get error snapshot after restarting node-red]

Comment: You will need to supply a lot more information before anybody can help here. Do you have any custom nodes installed. Can you show your actual flow?

Comment: Amit, that can sometimes happen if a loop is formed and two nodes endlessly try to update each other -- I suspect you need to uncheck the "Pass msg thru to output" option on one of the nodes. However, that's not possible to do in the editor if node-red will not start. In that case, I usually edit the `flow_hostname.json` file manually -- in a plain text editor, search for "passthru", change its value to `false`, save the file and restart node-red. Or, if you edit your question to include the flow JSON text, as @hardillb suggested, we can help you fix it...

Comment: Thanks... Thru terminal I edited flows_*.json(removed loop-wires)... Now, it's working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Opening root folder*

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /home/pi/.node-red

*Listing files of root*

pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red $ ls -l

total 48

-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 18820 Feb 22 01:59 flows_raspberrypi.json
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi pi  4096 Jan 23 14:53 lib
drwxr-xr-x 92 pi pi  4096 Jan 26 12:09 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi   198 Jan 26 12:09 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 10496 Jan 23 14:53 settings.js
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi pi  4096 Feb 20 19:37 uibuilder

*Editing Flow file*

pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red $ sudo nano flows_raspberrypi.json

*Then removed wires causing infinite-loop...*